# Rendering images instead video encoding

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have added an image sequence to the VSE and set the output at Quick time movie. When I click Animation then Blender starts rendering the first image instead the video encoding. Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to enable the sequencer in the post processing settings (found in the render context of the properties window).

[image]

Comment: I have the Sequencer checked.

Comment: See my own answer